# Unique[] symbol not properly tracked

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

In a nutshell, why does this work (change `y` and see how the value updates)

```
ClearAll[y];
Dynamic[x,
 Initialization :> (x = Symbol["y"])]
```

and then on a separate cell

```
y = 98;
```

but this doesn't? (assign the printed variable whatever value and see how it doesn't update)

```
Dynamic[x,
 Initialization :> (x = Unique[])]
```

You can also write `Dynamic[the printed var]` in a separate cell and see how it doesn't update either.

For now, I'll be using something that works and I would have never thought I would be using

```
Dynamic[x,
 Initialization :> (x = (Remove[#]; Symbol[#]) &@ToString@Unique[])]
```

My current weird conclusion: *"If a variable was declared by `Unique[]` inside a `Dynamic` update, then it will never be tracked by any `Dynamic` "*

Comment: Does using `Unique["xx"]` make any difference?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no it doesn't. Neither does `Unique["Global\`blah"]`

Comment: The bigger problem I'm trying to solve here, if anyone is wondering, is how to make a proper GUI control that internally uses some scheduled task

Comment: Weird. If you use `UpdateInterval -> 1` in the `Dynamic` it works as expected.

Comment: @SimonWoods the `Unique[]` version somehow creates a variable that isn't tracked with `Dynamic[$xxx]`. If you add a `Print@Unevaluated@kerVar` after `xx=7` you get the name of it and can test in a separate cell.

Comment: I didn't know that there was a way to do that, to "register" a variable not to either not trigger updates or not be tracked (don't know how to tell the difference between those two). Could be interesting

Comment: @SimonWoods, edited with a way simpler version

Comment: The first block of code doesn't work for me. The output stays at 98 no matter what I do to y. Though, the moment I copy the '98' and paste it somewhere else both show the new value of y.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, yes, same happens here. Strangely, that only happens if you run the first y=98; on the same cell as you run the `Dynamic`. Do it on a separate one

Comment: This has to do with Dynamic executing asynchronously. When given together in one cell block `y=98` is already executed before the `Dynamic` is fully finished.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries makes sense, yeah :)

Comment: Your simple version in the update, which I can now try, is quite baffling.

Comment: `Dynamic[x, Initialization :> ($ModuleNumber = 98; x = Unique[])]` (or any other fixed `$ModuleNumber` value) seems working fine.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. `$ModuleNumber = 98` works fine for me but `$ModuleNumber = 100` not.. Wired..

Comment: @Silvia that's weird, it doesn't work with either of them in (or should i say "on"? ...English) my system, which I think is the same as yours

Comment: @Rojo I tried again, seems it works only if being executed as the first `Dynamic` thing in a fresh-start Mathematica.

Comment: I give up. Shall we call it a bug?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries sure. I should mail Wolfram and see what comes back

Comment: I filed a bug report on this.  I can't explain the behavior, as it's produced by code that's outside of my expertise.

Comment: Not sure if ok, but I attempted this `With[{z = Unique[]}, Dynamic[w, Initialization :> (w = z)]]` and it prints *$nnn* and if you update *$nnn* that in other cell it gets updated. It seems you need an intermediate regular symbol (z) attached, which later gets discarded by the scoping construct. Is this an answer?

Comment: @rojo, see comment above. I dared to post this and my guess as to why as answer ;-)

Comment: @Rojo This issue seems to be fixed from 9.0.1. So as to add the bug header, can you tell which version this bug seemed to start? I suppose 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted this

```
With[{z = Unique[]}, Dynamic[w, Initialization :> (w = z)]]
```

and it prints *\$nnn* for some *nnn*. Then if you update the var *\$nnn* in other cell it gets updated. This may be a better code that the one you found.

I thought about why, but couldn't explain it. It seems `Dynamic` understands `Symbol` but doesn't understand `Unique`. The introduction of `With` seems to solve the shortcoming in `Dynamic` and I was speculating about a syntactic construct there but deleted my reply as it doesn't explain why `Dynamic` still works with `Symbol`.

Anyway, hope helps.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the updating issue, probably because the `Unique` isn't called during a dynamic update. However, for the same reason, it doesn't serve the same purpose as the original code. If you run this code, then `Quit` the kernel, and then start using `Unique` or perhaps even `Module` somewhere else, you might end up with the same variable name as in this dynamic cell...

Comment: I'm actually thinking of posting and accepting an answer such as "variables declared by Unique inside a Dynamic can't be tracked. I don't know if this is intended behaviour, but based on the comments it seems it isn't, and it has been reported". I was just hoping of some miracle explanation or setting

Comment: @rojo, I believe you should say "symbols created with `Unique`" instead of *variables*. The oddity is that symbols created with `Symbol` still work. So I bet `Dynamic` does more than a simple syntactic (but at runtime) resolution of dependency.